# Orthodox traveller in Catholic lands

Tags: middle-ages, religion, travel

What would the options have been for a member of the Orthodox church have been for religious observations while travelling in Catholic countries during the middle-ages?

Presumably someone travelling with a large entourage could bring a priest along with them; but I'm more interested in people travelling alone or in small groups -- envoys, couriers, small merchants, etc.

Comment: Options for what?  Where?  When?

Comment: Same options as when traveling to Muslim countries, China, India, etc.